# How can I enforce a powershell script extension runs on all new VMs in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I've written a PowerShell script and Linux bash script that I run to setup a management account inside Azure VMs and configures WMI or SNMP so I can monitor them properly. Works great! I just push out a new VM and then either run the PowerShell/Bash script via an extension during or after creation, all good.

However, I have other admins that also create VMs in the subscription that keep forgetting to run the extension and then I have to pick it up afterwards when I notice the monitoring system can't connect to them properly. How can I either:

- Automatically enforce either the Linux or Windows extension to any new VMs that are created by other admins
- Create some kind of automated policy that checks for VMs that haven't had the extension run and runs the extension in them
- Or something else that will achieve what I need

Does anyone have any hints or links to articles that I could follow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Azure Policy has a built-in policy that only allows a set list of extension: found here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/built-in-policies#compute. However, you are able to do a custom policy with a DeployIfNotExist policy that will deploy an arm template with those extensions. Here is another customer sample on that: https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/samples/Compute/deploy-oms-vm-extension-windows-vm/azurepolicy.rules.json